# Why does jsoup.parse() doesn't return the full HTML document?

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I am tinkering around with Jsoup and I wonder why does jsoup.parse(url) returns a partial part of the HTML. Here is my code:

```
System.out.println(Jsoup.parse("https://www.example.com"))
```

Here is the output

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  https://www.example.com
 </body>
</html>
```

It is partial at best, and if you go to www.example.com you would see that the parser missed two `<p>` tags.

Now the docs say this

> public static Document parse​(String html)
>
> Parse HTML into a Document. As no base URI is specified, absolute URL
>   detection
>
> relies on the HTML including a  tag.
>
> Parameters: html - HTML to parse
>
> Returns: sane HTML

It says it brings back a document, but in practice its a partial one. Also - what is "sane" HTML?

Comment: You've not given it an HTML document to parse, but rather a very simple String, one that looks like a path to an HTML.

Comment: You may wish to use `Jsoup.connect(STRING_PATH_TO_HTML).get();` or something similar to get a real HTML

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks. Awesome username :)